# Echo Array from While once

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I'm trying to output the result of an array I fill from an SQL database.

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($Difference))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Difference))
        {
            $block[] = $row["time"]." | ".$row["d_bl"];
        }
}?>
```

When I "vardump" the array, it contains all the proper values I expect.
I want to output this array now in a simple list with breaks.
When I use "return" with the array, I only get one result due the automatic escape. When I print the array, I get 150 times the array instead of only the 150 once, due the loop.

Comment: use a foreach loop and var_dump $value, you should be getting an array of arrays's

Comment: Where is your print?

Comment: `foreach($block as $b) echo $b['time'] . '|' . $b['d_bl']`;

Comment: where did you write return?

Comment: so surely you can just put the return or print _outside_ your loop then

Comment: After your while loop has finished - `echo implode("<br />", $block);` (Assuming web page output - replace `"<br />"` with `PHP_EOL` if not)

Comment: Thank you @Nigel Ren for the awesome solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from @Nigel Ren

After your while loop has finished -

```
echo implode("<br />", $block);
```

(Assuming web page output - replace `"<br />"` with `PHP_EOL` if not)